# Comparator with LimitFilter not work

Tags: java, caching, comparator, oracle-coherence

I'm trying to retrieve result from cache using a limitFilter :

```
class Student {
    long studentId;
}

class StudentComparator implements Comparator<Student> {
    public int compare(Student o1, Student o2) {
       return o1.getStudentId() - o2.getStudentId();
    }
}

StudentComparator studentComparator = new StudentComparator();
EntryComparator comparator = new EntryComparator(studentComparator,EntryComparator.CMP_VALUE);
LimitFilter limitFilter = new LimitFilter(AlwaysFilter.INSTANCE, 5)
limitFilter.setComparator(comparator);
Set studentSet = null;
do {
   studentSet = studentCache.entrySet(limitFilter);
   .....
   // print the set
   .....
   limitFilter.nextPage();
} while (studentSet.size() > 0)
```

According to the API

```
 public void setComparator(Comparator comparator) : Set the Comparator
 used to partition the values into pages.
```

So I expected the limitfilter will sort the data using the comparator but it seem not doing so. For example, I have 20 student with the studentId range from 1 to 20. I expect there are 4 studentSet with the do/while loop that have ranges : 1-5, 6-10, 11-15, 16-20 respectively. But sometime there is a Student with Id 13 in the first studentSet or 2 in the last studentSet, etc.

Have anyone encountered this problem, please let me know your idea

Comment: Is it the case that your first student set does not get 1-5 entries but some random entries like 2,6,3,12,1. In that case comparator will just sort these entries and put in the first student set. Check what you are getting as part of First Student Set.

Comment: Yes, the first Set has random entries And I don't think they are sorted either, the method for sort the result is NamedCache.entrySet(filter, comparator).

Answer (score 1):

According to JavaDoc for `LimitFilter.setComparator(Comparator comparator)` (for Coherence 12.2.1 at least)

> This method is intended to be used only by query processors. Clients should not modify the content of this property.

To get the described result, you should call (inside the loop):

```
studentSet = studentCache.entrySet(limitFilter, comparator);
```